# Python loading bar with milestones

Tags: python, loading

Im trying to make a underground controlling program with visualisation (for fun of course ;D). I know there are many different loading bar libraries but I couldnt find anything wiht milestones if you know what I mean. Im using Python 3 on windows. I will be thankfull for  any help

Comment: What do you mean with a "milestone" in a progress bar? From my understanding, something like [nested progress bars](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#nested-progress-bars) could be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A loading bar with milestones can be achived with sys:

```
def updt(total, progress):
    barLength, status = 25, ""
    progress = float(progress) / float(total)
    if progress >= 1.:
      progress, status = 1, "\r\n"
    block = int(round(barLength * progress))
    text = "\r[{}] {:.0f}% {}".format(
        "#" * block + "-" * (barLength - block), round(progress * 100, 0),
    status)
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()


    runs = 250
        for run_num in range(runs):
        time.sleep(.1)
        updt(runs, run_num + 1)
        time.sleep(1)
```